# .ppm file separate every 3 pixels

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, image, file

I have this code, that should ultimately mirror the ppm image. but I'm facing a problem is trying to separate every 3 pixels into its own brackets in a lists of lists.

for example I have this `.ppm` file:

```
P3 
44 
15
000 000  000 15015 
000 0157 000 000 
000 000  0157 000 
15015 000 000 000
```

I want to separate into lists of lists with every 3 pixels in brackets like this Ignoring the header:

```
[[('0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0'), ('15', '0', '15')], [('0', '0', '0'), ('0', '15', '7'), ('0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0')], [('0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0'), ('0', '15', '7'), ('0', '0', '0')], [('15', '0', '15'), ('0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0')]]
```

so far I've only been able to achieve this:

```
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '15', '0', '15'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '15', '7', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '15', '7', '0', '0', '0'], ['15', '0', '15', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

how can I separate each three integers in the list of lists?

code:

```
takePPM = input("Enter the pmm file name: ")
openFile = open(takePPM, "r")
readFile = openFile.readlines()
lists = []
for row in readFile[3:]:
    lists.append(row.split())

print(lists)
```

Comment: Your PPM file is incorrect, by the way. There should be 255 inserted after the third line. And the R, G and B components of each pixel should be separated by spaces.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Its my first time working with PPM files, so I'm not sure of how to do it properly. this is how I got the file. only 3 lines for the header followed by the pixels

Comment: Have a look here... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PPM_example

Comment: Note that **ImageMagick**, **Photoshop**, **GIMP**, **feh**, **eog** and many other tools can understand, generate and display PPM files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the data you want placed nicely into `lists`, the following should work:

```
#convert each list in lists to lists of 3-tuples
target = []
for list in lists:
    target.append([tuple(list[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(list),3)])

print(target) #target list with lists of 3-tuples
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, this means a lot 

Comment: No problem.  How did you get the result ```lists```?  It seems when I tried to implement your code on my machine, the ```lists``` you posted here and the one I got were different.

Comment: using the ```.split()``` function seems to create the list of lists, as it is separating it by ```\n```